# strip/trim URL path/string to leave just the end file name string after specified character using php

Tags: php

This is a really easy question, but I can't figure out what I should be using exactly.

My `$image['url']` is **http://hello.com/uploads/2012/name.jpg**

So I want to just be left with this... **name.jpg**

I tried lots but I think explode is the one I should use but I just get `array` outputted from this.

```
$filename = explode('/', $image['url']);

echo $filename;
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction on the php manual.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was mostly right, just lacking an [array_pop()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to extract last element of array returned by `explode()`, like this:

```
$filename = array_pop(explode('/', $image['url']));

echo $filename; //echoes 'name.jpg'
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks for explaining that. This definitely solves my original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty tempted to say you can just use [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) here and it will work with a URL or relative path:

```
$filename = basename($image['url']);
```

This will return the trailing name component of path, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`$filename = basename($image['url']);` should give you what you need. (more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the built-in PHP function [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).